# Setting up oEmbed provider to enable embedding site content on Pinterest

Tags: pinterest, oembed

We are looking to setup a site as oEmbed provider.
Official docs (http://oembed.com/) say:

> Configuration for oEmbed is very simple. Providers must specify one or
>   more URL scheme and API endpoint pairs. The URL scheme describes which
>   URLs provided by the service may have an embedded representation. The
>   API endpoint describes where the consumer may request representations
>   for those URLs.

This is quite straightforward how to set up API endpoint to return some efficient information about URL provided as request parameter. But the question is how and where providers should specify those URL scheme and API endpoint pairs.

If you have experience of going with oembed  provider for pinterest that is perfectly what I need to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I was looking for the same. The answer is now on the page http://oembed.com/ (heading 7)

**7.1. Providers**

Providers are available programatically as a json file: http://oembed.com/providers.json.

To add new providers, please fork [this](https://github.com/iamcal/oembed) repo on GitHub and modify providers.yml.